How to extract the class template of an object without its template-parameters?
How do I extract the template of an object to declare a new object with different template parameters ?
If it is even possible, I'm looking for something with the following usage :
#include <vector>
#include <array>

int main() 
{
  std::vector<float> a;
  std::array<int, 7> b;

  get_template<decltype(a), unsigned> new_a; // std::vector<unsigned>
  get_template<decltype(b), float, 85> new_b; // std::array<float, 85>

  return 0;
}


get_template(a)<int> is not valid syntax btw. Looks like pseudo-code.

Do you want to cast type of vector or array to another type? I don't think this is possible, also you resized the array which you can't!

Just writing std::vector and std::array would be the simplest/clearest option. Also I don't think this is possible though. Atleast doing this for all possible templates.


How do I extract the template of an object to declare a new object with different template parameters?
If it is even possible [...]

Yes, something along the following lines you can:
// Primary template
template<typename T> struct get_template;

// Specialization for std::vector
template<typename T, typename Allocator>
struct get_template<std::vector<T, Allocator>> {
   template<typename U, typename UAllocator = std::allocator<U>>
   using type = std::vector<U, UAllocator>;
};

// Specialization for std::array
template<typename T, std::size_t N>
struct get_template<std::array<T, N>> {
   template<typename U, std::size_t UN = N>
   using type = std::array<U, UN>;
};

// ... so on for other containers!

// Helper alias for both specializations
template<typename Container, typename U, auto... Ts>
using get_template_t = typename get_template<Container>::template type<U, Ts...>;

You would use it like:
std::vector<float> a;
std::array<int, 7> b;

get_template_t<decltype(a), unsigned> new_a; // std::vector<unsigned>
get_template_t<decltype(b), float, 85> new_b; // std::array<float, 85>

See live demo

Is specialization unavoidable for the tool that I'm looking for ?
I hoped for something generic but I may be asking for too much

@john3743 Not, that I can (currently) think of. Someone else can (maybe) generalize the above idea by MORE template magics and the latest language features!

You can specialise for specific combinations of type and non-type parameters, but you can't have a fully generic solution.
// Primary template
template<typename T> struct get_template;

// Specialization for types with no non-type parameters
template<template<typename...> typename Container, typename... Ts>
struct get_template<Container<Ts...>> {
   template<typename... Us>
   using type = Container<Us...>;
};

// Specialization for types with a type parameter followed by non-type parameters
template<template<typename, auto...> typename Container, typename T, auto... Ns>
struct get_template<Container<T, Ns...>> {
   template<typename U, auto... UNs>
   using type = Container<U, UNs...>;
};

template<typename Container, typename... Us>
using get_template_t = typename get_template<Container>::template type<Us...>;

template<typename Container, typename T, auto... Us>
using get_template_value_t = typename get_template<Container>::template type<T, Us...>;

std::vector<float> a;
std::array<int, 7> b;

static_assert(std::same_as<get_template_t<decltype(a), unsigned>, std::vector<unsigned>>);
static_assert(std::same_as<get_template_value_t<decltype(b), float, 85>, std::array<float, 85>>);

